# Test Eclipse 4 RCP Application. Provide necessary Objects

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I´m developing an Eclipse 4 RCP Application and I want to test some functions of my Parts. 
I have a Test Class like this:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void initUI() {
    display = new Display();
    shell = new Shell(display);

    configPart = new ConfigPart();
    configPart.postConstruct(shell);
}

@Test
public void testConfigPart() {
    String testText = "TitleText";
    configPart.title.setText(testText);

    assertEquals(testText, ConfigHandler.getInstance().getInternalConfig()
            .getTitle());
}
```

During the creation of the ConfigPart a DataBinding is created and that is where I run into an AssertionFailedException. The statement is:

```
DataBindingContext ctx = new DataBindingContext();
```

Is there a way to avoid this or is there another way to test E4 Applications?

Edit: 
The statement(s) where the Exception is raised:

```
public DataBindingContext(Realm validationRealm) {
    Assert.isNotNull(validationRealm, "Validation realm cannot be null"); 

public static void isNotNull(Object object, String message) { 
    if (object == null) throw new AssertionFailedException("null argument:" + message);
```

The Stack Trace:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:Validation realm cannot be null
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.DataBindingContext.<init>(DataBindingContext.java:95)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.DataBindingContext.<init>(DataBindingContext.java:82)
at de.uni_due.s3.jack.editor.parts.config.ConfigPart.addDataBinding(ConfigPart.java:350)
at de.uni_due.s3.jack.editor.parts.config.ConfigPart.postConstruct(ConfigPart.java:81)
at de.uni_due.s3.jack.editor.parts.config.ConfigPartTest.initUI(ConfigPartTest.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: You can't really test e4 parts like this as you aren't going to get any injection and e4 will not be initialized properly.

Comment: Okay so there is no way to run such tests automatically from code?

Comment: If you want to test the UI, you can maybe use this useful link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWTBot/article.html

Comment: There must be some way because Eclipse themselves run lots of tests, but I don't know what they use

Comment: Is the assertion failing because of `Validation realm cannot be null`?

Comment: yes it is. The call is:
public DataBindingContext(Realm validationRealm) {
  Assert.isNotNull(validationRealm, "Validation realm cannot be null"); 
public static void isNotNull(Object object, String message) {
  if (object == null)
   throw new AssertionFailedException("null argument:" + message); //$NON-NLS-1$
 }

Comment: The code is barely readable. Could you edit the question accordingly and also amend the stacktrace?

Comment: It looks as if your setup method is run from a non-UI thread. Is there a reason why you use @BeforeClass instead of @Before?

Comment: Are you running the test as a PDE JUnit test or a plain JUnit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to the empty constructor `new DataBindingContext()` delegates to `this(Realm.getDefault())` (see Eclipse source code). This means that you need to have some kind of a stub Realm set as default for your testing purposes.

You can use this [solution from the Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding/Realm). Here is a copy-paste from the Wiki (adapted for your setup). I would think about whether you really need to have the setup in `@BeforeClass` or if `@Before` would be better.

```
public class DefaultRealm extends Realm {
    private Realm previousRealm;

    public DefaultRealm() {
        previousRealm = super.setDefault(this);
    }

    /**
     * @return always returns true
     */
    public boolean isCurrent() {
        return true;
    }

    protected void syncExec(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }

    /**
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException
     */
    public void asyncExec(Runnable runnable) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("asyncExec is unsupported");
    }

    /**
     * Removes the realm from being the current and sets the previous realm to the default.
     */
    public void dispose() {
        if (getDefault() == this) {
            setDefault(previousRealm);
        }
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
private static DefaultRealm realm;

@BeforeClass
public static void initUI() {
    display = new Display();
    shell = new Shell(display);

    realm = new DefaultRealm();

    configPart = new ConfigPart();
    configPart.postConstruct(shell);
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownUI() {
    realm.dispose();
}
```